# Group duplicated rows in the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to group duplicated rows by the same person and count how many rows are there. 
I'm using this SQL command but it isn't showing all rows, I can see some new rows but in this command aren't showing 
The SQL command I'm using is :

```
SELECT seller, count(id) AS value_sum , type, date, sold, type2
FROM  accounts
GROUP BY type, seller
HAVING (FROM_UNIXTIME(date) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND sold='0' 
ORDER BY rand()
```

Where is the problem that it isn't showing some rows?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Yes, sample data and expected results please. What do you call "duplicated rows"? What do you mean with "I want to group rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first reaction is that the `having` clause should be a `where` clause.  Then you should only include unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are in the `GROUP BY`.

You can see the `sellers` with duplicated rows as:

```
SELECT seller, count(id) AS cnt
FROM  accounts
WHERE (FROM_UNIXTIME(date) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND sold = 0
GROUP BY seller
ORDER BY rand();
```

This would appear to solve the problem that you are describing.